# Normal Distribution without Standard Deviation

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Speeds of automobiles on a certain stretch of I-85 at 4:00pm are normally distributed with a mean of 65 mph. 20% of cars are traveling at speeds between 55 and 65mph. What percentage of the cars is going faster than 75mph. Explain your reasoning.

EDIT: Once I find the standard deviation, I know how to solve the problem. I'm having the most trouble determining what the standard deviation is. Should I just plug in numbers for σ in the normalcdf command on the graphing calculator or is there are more accurate way to determine the standard deviation?

Comment: Could you show us some of the calculations or how you have already approached this problem?

Comment: I'm kind of stuck, because I'm not sure how to calculate the standard deviation. I know because of the Empirical Rule that I need to figure out what roughly 68% of the population falls under to find the standard deviation. I also know that 45-55 will hold less than 20%, since it is normally distributed. So far, I've just plugged in different standard deviations into the normalcdf command to get (65,?,55,65) = 0.2. I'm thinking it's close to 19, but I'm not sure and really having trouble figuring out where to start.

Comment: Try adding your thoughts/workings into the questions with an edit so people can give you the most appropriate answer

Comment: hint: if 20% of cars travel at the speed between 55-65, then due to symmetry 20% of cars travel at the speed between 65-75. And you need to find the percentage of cars that travel at the speed greater than 75.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* find the standard deviation, but it is not necessary to do so. The normal distribution is symmetrical about its mean $\mu = 65$ mph. If 20% are at speeds 55 to 65mph, then the rest of the 50% traveling below 65mph are the 30% going slower than 55mph.

Then, by symmetry, there are 20% going between 65 and 75mph, and 30% going faster than 75mph.

---

If you are also asked to find $\sigma,$ then let
$X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 65, \sigma)$ be the
speed of a randomly selected car. You know
that

$$P(55 < X < 65) = P\left(\frac{55-65}{\sigma} < Z < \frac{65-65}{\sigma}=0\right) = 0.20,$$

where $Z$ is standard normal. From printed normal
tables you can deduce the value of $-10/\sigma$ and
thus of $\sigma.$

---

Here is a plot of the normal distribution of the speeds of the cars. From left to right areas separated by vertical red lines correspond to probabilities .3, .2, .2, .3, respectively.

[image]